# Center number of pages Discord Bot

Tags: python, button, uibutton, pycord

I'm currently having a problem to center the number of pages between the navigation buttons

he ends up being like this

[image]

But whenever I change pages, It goes to the direction I click the navigation button

[image]

I use the pycord lib for the navigation buttons, the code looks like this:

```
    @commands.slash_command()
    async def help(self, ctx):
      """
      Mostrar a página de ajuda.
      """
      paginator = pages.Paginator(
          pages=self.pages, show_disabled=False)
      await paginator.respond(ctx.interaction, ephemeral=False)
      await Session.delete_message(self, ctx, 60)
```

I can't imagine how to use it without creating the navigation buttons myself, so the question is, is it possible to do this using the pycord lib?

Comment: `@commands.slash_command()` is not `discord.py` so you're using something else here. Either way, `Buttons` are now built-in in 2.0 so yes it's perfectly possible. The order you add them to your view is the order they are displayed in discord, and you can modify the items afterwards.

Comment: I ended up getting confused that `@commands.slash_command()` is from `PyCord`, not `discord.py`, but your explanation has helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I arrived at the solution, instantiating the buttons directly in the function

```
@commands.slash_command()
async def help(self, ctx: discord.ApplicationContext):
    """
    Mostrar a página de ajuda.
    """
    paginator = pages.Paginator(
        pages=self.pages,
        use_default_buttons=False,
        loop_pages=False,
        show_disabled=False,
    )
    paginator.add_button(
        pages.PaginatorButton(
            "prev", label="<", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, loop_label="lst"
        )
    )
    paginator.add_button(
        pages.PaginatorButton(
            "page_indicator", style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray, disabled=True
        )
    )
    paginator.add_button(
        pages.PaginatorButton(
            "next", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, loop_label="fst"
            )
        )
        await paginator.respond(ctx.interaction, ephemeral=False)
```

[API about](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/ext/pages/index.html#paginatorbutton)